# Using metric tensor to contract

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

Can the metric tensor also contract the indices in the $$\epsilon^{\tau\lambda\mu\nu}~?$$

For example, if we have $$g_{\tau\tau'}g_{\lambda\lambda'}g_{\mu\mu'}g_{\nu\nu'}\epsilon^{\tau\lambda\mu\nu}$$ do we get $$\epsilon_{\tau'\lambda'\mu'\nu'}~?$$

Comment: Yes, it works exactly as you described.

Comment: I don't know if it's standard to call that contraction of the indices of $\epsilon^{\tau\lambda\mu\nu}$. Rather, one would normally call that lowering of the indices. Alternatively, perhaps you might say that the metric tensor can contract with $\epsilon^{\tau\lambda\mu\nu}$ to lower its indices.

Comment: That is part of the metric's duty...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what do you mean by $\epsilon^{\tau\lambda\mu\nu}$. When it represents the Levi-Civita *symbol*, while you can technically perform this operation component-wise, it would be quite meaningless, since the Levi-Civita *symbol* is not the representation of a tensor field.

However, in coordinate index-based formulations of general relativity and Riemannian geometry, it is customary to introduce a $\varepsilon_{\tau\lambda\mu\nu}=\sqrt{|\det(g)|}\epsilon_{\tau\lambda\mu\nu}$ quantity (note the stylistic difference between the two epsilons, though conventions vary with literature), which is (the respresentation of) a tensor field, usually called the Levi-Civita *tensor*, or in more modern literature (that makes references to differential forms, if not outright using them), canonical/invariant volume form.

Since the Levi-Civita *tensor* is a tensor field, you can perform all tensorial operations on it, such as contractions, lowering/raising, etc.